# read csv file through windows batch file and create txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have an excel file with 5 values each in a line. now, i want to read the .csv file through batch file and create text file with the contents in the file.
Example, if i have Apple, Mango in csv file (in one column), then the batch file should read this .csv file and should create a text file like " Apple is a fruit" and in next line " Mango is a fruit". Can anyone share the code please.

Comment: Edit sample input and output data into your question to clarify it. You'd find selecting a pasted copy and pressing the `{}` icon may be helpful.

Comment: Hi I have tried the code which you have given, but instead of recording the data, it is recording the path of the file. 'FOR %%A IN ('C:\temp\fruit.csv') DO ( echo %%A is a fruit >>test.txt ) ' 
O/p:  Mango is a fruit

Comment: Why use batch in the first place? This is a lot simpler in PowerShell, as `Import-Csv` is built in.

Answer (score 12):

there are a lot of similar questions answered in SOF. Few of them to refer are :

[Reading from a csv file and extracting certain data columns based on first column value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473239/windows-batch-programming-reading-from-a-csv-file-and-extracting-certain-data)

[Help in writing a batch script to parse CSV file and output a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470570/help-in-writing-a-batch-script-to-parse-csv-file-and-output-a-text-file)

[How do you loop in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355791/batch-file-loop)

Simplest answer is to loop thru your file using:

```
FOR %A IN (list) DO command [ parameters ]
```

Example:

Sample CSV:

```
0,1,2,4
1,1,2,3
2,2,4,6
3,3,6,9
```

bat file content:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1-4 delims=," %%a in ("sample1.csv") do (
      echo %%a %%b %%c %%d )
```

here tokens=1-4 meaning that we wish to read 4 column data for each line

Comment: Hi Girish, thankyou for the quick reply. I have tried the code which you have given, but instead of recording the data, it is recording the path of the file.
'FOR  %%A IN ('C:\temp\fruit.csv') DO (
  echo %%A >>test.txt
 ) '

Comment: What if the CSV contains this 1,2,"apples,bananas",4? it should print  string `apples, bananas` for index 3, but it seems to ignore quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I had thought to convert file using powershell in the FOR command but it's just much easier and simpler to get command line to parse the file itself using parameters.

> ```
> @echo off rem     findstr "@SPC@" sample3.csv&& echo ERROR: source has our space encoding& goto :EOF
>  for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (sample3.csv) do (
>    set x_line=%%a
>    set x_line=!x_line: =@SPC@!
>    set x_line=!x_line:^&=@AND@!
>    set x_line=!x_line:^|=@POR@!
>    call :parcsv %%a& rem dangerous unless you parsed properly
>  )
>  goto :EOF
>
> :parcsv
>  set x_cola=%~1
>  set x_colb=%~2
>  set x_colc=%~3
>  set x_cold=%~4
>  for %%v in ( x_cola x_colb x_colc x_cold 
>  ) do set %%v=!%%v:@POR@=^|!& set %%v=!%%v:@AND@=^&! set %%v=!%%v:@SPC@= !
>  echo "!x_cola!"  "!x_colb!" "!x_colc!"   "!x_cold!"
>  goto :EOF
> ```

This would properly handle a file with a line: 1,2,"apples,bananas",4.
or used to convert comma delimited file into tab delimited etc.

Or actually on second thought it now breaks: 1,2,"orange bananas",5 and a half,6

So I needed to update FOR /F line from the original: for /F "tokens=* delims=," %%a in (sample.csv) do call :parcsv %%a
So it uses an alternate character or code rather than space.

On and on 3rd review... it's really really bad because if you have "&" in a line you can break out of the bat file and hack yourself... so we would need to encode "&" and "|" and perhaps more!!!  so let's go up and update those things too...

So perhaps powershell hybrid oneliner isn't so bad:

```
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=  " %%a in ('powershell "import-csv sample.csv|convertto-csv -d `t"') do echo a:[%%a] b:[%%b] c:[%%c] d:[%%d]
```